# Filtering out 2 conditions from a csv file

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I need to Calculate percentage of males that are offered a job, the percentage of males not offered a job, the percentage of females offered a job and the percentage of females not offered a job. I have a csv file with Gender (M/F) and Status (Offered/Not offered). I have tried the below function  but i don't know how to change the salary part to the required gender.

**filter dataframe**

```
display(dataFrame.loc[(dataFrame['Salary']>=100000) & (dataFrame['Age']< 40) & (dataFrame['JOB'].str.startswith('D')),
                    ['Name','JOB']])
```

Comment: Did you try `(dataFrame['Gender']=='M')`, or something like that?

Comment: this is what i have tried .  display(CollegeXMBA.csv['Gender']=='M') & (CollegeXMBA.csv['Status']== Offered)